# use for each to get each input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm expecting value 1 and 2 but it returned null instead. Any idea why is this happening?

```js
$(function() {

  $('.agent_rows').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('input[name="associatedAgentId"]').val())
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="agent_rows">
  <input type="hidden" name="associatedAgentId" value="1">
</div>

<div class="agent_rows">
  <input type="hidden" name="associatedAgentId" value="2">
</div>
```

Comment: Try `.value()` instead

Comment: @JanDvorak LoL. You are telling the opposite. It should be `value=` and `.val()`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: there is no method called `value()`

Comment: @OP, see the magic after your edit. What is the point of editing after getting the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You have set incorrect attribute. it should be `value` instead of `val` in attribute:

```
 <div class="agent_rows">
   <input type="hidden" name="associatedAgentId" value="1">
 </div>

 <div class="agent_rows">
   <input type="hidden" name="associatedAgentId" value="2">
 </div>
```

Comment: Er... Why can't you wait for a second. `:P` So fast you are!

Answer (score 0):

It should be `value` not `val`:

```
<div class="agent_rows">
  <input type="hidden" name="associatedAgentId" value="1">
</div>

<div class="agent_rows">
  <input type="hidden" name="associatedAgentId" value="2">
</div>
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.agent_rows').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('input[name="associatedAgentId"]').val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="agent_rows">
  <input type="hidden" name="associatedAgentId" value="1">
</div>

<div class="agent_rows">
  <input type="hidden" name="associatedAgentId" value="2">
</div>
```